# Can anyone help me in writing a cron job

Tags: linux

I want to execute a task on second Sunday of every month at 9a.m and 9p.m
please help me out.

I was trying this:

```
0 9,21 * * 0/2 task in the cron file
```

Comment: why don't you change it to today and see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`0 9 */15 * 0 task`

`0 21 */15 * 0 task`

Comment: That will execute on every sunday, not only on the second sunday of every month.

Comment: I updated my answer.